# Uninstall Vertica on multi-node cluster

Tags: vertica

I have a multi-node Vertica 7.0 cluster. I did some research on how to remove it. Based on the documentation, the steps are very simple and straight forward.

I just need to log in to each host in the cluster and remove the package: `rpm -e package`

Also if I want to delete the configuration file used with the installation, I can remove the directory: `rm -rf /opt/vertica/`

My question is, if I have 20 nodes in the cluster, do I really need to do that on each node? I know the installation of multi-node cluster is much easier cause we can install it without having to go to each node and install the rpm file.

How about uninstallation? What is the best practice to uninstall a multi-node cluster?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you breaking up with Vertica?

Answer (score 0):

The way you found out is indeed the only way. Note that you would need to remove the data and catalog directories as well.

To make your life easier, [ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) is an amazing tool. Once you define an ansible host file (basically the list of your vertica servers in a [vertica] section, ini-style), you can just run one command:

```
ansible vertica -mshell -a 'yum uninstall vertica'
ansible vertica -mshell -a 'rm -rf /opt/vertica'
```

and so on. It will automagically run on all servers of your cluster. You will probably need to play with the -s, -S or -k options to use the root user, but ansible will definitely make your life a lot easier.